# Gradle runs out of memory on Travis

Tags: gradle, travis-ci, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dokka

I'm trying to get [this build](https://travis-ci.com/github/andreihh/chronolens/builds) to pass on Travis, but Gradle runs out of memory when running the `./gradlew :chronolens-test:dokkaJavadoc` task.

When I run the task locally, it passes. I tried increasing the Gradle memory (e.g., in [in this commit](https://github.com/andreihh/chronolens/commit/b373a10646e71e233acb5e94ad25403f79dcf05c)), but to no avail. According to [Travis documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/), I believe the environment I configured should have at least 7 GB of RAM, so Gradle using up to 2-3 GB shouldn't be an issue (especially since it passes locally with the same RAM settings).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas on how I can make the build green?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a known issue of dokka itself: https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1405

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I think you're right, that's quite unfortunate.

I tried the suggested fix of increasing metaspace memory (but I used 2 GB instead of the suggested 512 MB / 1GB), still to no avail...

Comment: Nevermind... It worked after lowering the memory to 1 GB and pulling the settings into a top-level gradle.properties file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Francisco Mateo [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65656428/gradle-runs-out-of-memory-on-travis?noredirect=1#comment116086978_65656428), this is a [known issue of Dokka](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1405). As recommended in [this duplicate issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/issues/1508), setting the metaspace memory in a top-level `gradle.properties` file eventually worked and fixed the build on Travis.